# Why is this program not detecting the mode correctly?

Tags: java, math

I have a program that finds the mode of an array. Here is the code:

```
                System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to find the mode of? ");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                Arrays.sort(inputs);
                int count2 = 0;
                int count1 = 0;
                double popular1 = 0;
                double popular2 = 0;
                //finds most popular value in the array
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        popular1 = inputs[i];
                        count1 = 1;
                    for(int j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                        if(popular1 == inputs[j]) {
                            count1++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count1 > count2) {
                        popular2 = popular1;
                        count2 = count1;
                    } else if(count1 == count2) {
                        popular2 = Math.min(popular2, popular1); //when there are two winners, the lowest one is the mode
                    }
                }  

                finalans = "The mode of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + popular2 + ", with a staggering " + count1 + " appearances.";
                return finalans;
```

However when ran, I'm not getting the desired output. 1st, it doesn't count correctly, 2nd, it doesn't always detect which number is the mean. Just in case it is necessary, the full program is below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean again = true;
        
        while(again == true) {
            
            System.out.println(runMath());
            
            System.out.println("Do you want to run again? true or false");
            again = scanner.nextBoolean();

        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }
    
    public static String runMath() {
        double solution1;
        double solution2;
        String finalans;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Operation ID? 1 = Add, 2 = Sub, 3 = Mul, 4 = Div, 5 = Ave");
        int ID = scanner.nextInt();
        solution1 = 0;
        solution2 = 0;
        
        switch (ID) {
        case 1: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to add?");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    solution1 += inputs[i];
                }
                finalans = "The sum of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}   
        case 2: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to subtract?");
                System.out.println("All numbers are subtracted from the first number, in inputted order.");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                solution1 = inputs[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    solution1 -= inputs[i];
                }
                finalans = "The difference of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}
        case 3: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to multiply?");
                double inputs[] = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                solution1 = inputs[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    solution1 *= inputs[i];
                }
                finalans = "The product of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}
        case 4: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to divide?");
                System.out.println("All numbers are subtracted from the first number, in inputted order.");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                solution1 = inputs[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    solution1 /= inputs[i];
                }
                finalans = "The quotient of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}
        case 5: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to average?");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    solution1 += inputs[i];
                }
                solution1 /= inputs.length;
                finalans = "The mean of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}
        case 6: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to find the median of?");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i  = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                Arrays.sort(inputs);
                if(inputs.length % 2 == 0) {
                    solution1 = (inputs[inputs.length / 2] + inputs[inputs.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
                } else solution1 = inputs[inputs.length / 2];
                finalans = "The median of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + solution1;
                return finalans;}
        case 7: {System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to find the mode of? ");
                double[] inputs = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
                    inputs[i] = (double) scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                Arrays.sort(inputs);
                int count2 = 0;
                int count1 = 0;
                double popular1 = 0;
                double popular2 = 0;
                //finds most popular value in the array
                for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        popular1 = inputs[i];
                        count1 = 1;
                    for(int j = i + 1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                        if(popular1 == inputs[j]) {
                            count1++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count1 > count2) {
                        popular2 = popular1;
                        count2 = count1;
                    } else if(count1 == count2) {
                        popular2 = Math.min(popular2, popular1); //when there are two winners, the lowest one is the mode
                    }
                }  

                finalans = "The mode of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + popular2 + ", with a staggering " + count1 + " appearances.";
                return finalans;}
        default: return "ur mom";
        }
    }
    
}
```

Thank you to any geniuses that might solve this!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your input, your current and expected output.

Comment: Did you already step through your code with a debugger and check the calculations and intermediate results? If not, you might want to start doing so and learn how to do it (pretty easy with any decent IDE).

Comment: you do not need to cast this scanner.nextDouble(); to double it already return double
and in your final stringn you use count1 while you should use count2
this is not required else if(count1 == count2) {
                        popular2 = Math.min(popular2, popular1); //when there are two winners, the lowest one is the mode
                    }
as popular2 will always be lower than any popular1 as you already sorted the array

Comment: and as @Thomas said using the debug mode of your ide would make it easy for you to trace the execution of your program

Comment: One thing that seems odd: `count2` seems to represent the highest count while `count1` seems to be a temporary variable. However, in your output you're using `count1` - probably accidently. This would be a good point to emphasize meaningful names for everything, including local variables.

Comment: @Stef this problem should not occur because of the `Arrays.sort(inputs);` before counting the number of occurrences

Comment: Thomas; I think that is why! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just tested it- it works as expected now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've noticed in your code that you use `count1` as a temporary container for your current loop. So you should use `count2` in your `finalans` instead of `count1`.

```
  finalans = "The mode of those " + inputs.length + " numbers is " + popular2 + ", with a staggering " + count2 + " appearances.";
```